# I have 10 nodes .. each node has known number of transceivers .. I want to know How can I obtain all possible connections between nodes ? using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have 10 nodes .. each node has known number of transceivers as indicated in this vector:

```
[8 3 3 3 3 3 2 1 1 1]
```

where: 8 is the number of transceivers at the 1st node, 3 is the number of transceivers at the 2nd node and so on ..

Each transceiver can only receive from one source at a time .. it is required that all transceivers must be in use simultaneously .. it is permitted for the same node to use more than one transceiver to transmit to another node that has enough transceivers to receive with .. it is not possible for a single transceiver to be considered to be transmitting to multiple transceivers ..

I want to know How can I obtain all possible connections between nodes and each obtained connection matrix identify the number of transceivers used between the connected nodes ?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question. I have no idea how you want to represent a connection between your specified nodes. What exactly is your desired output? Have you tried any code that might help us understand what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do this in `Matlab`.
With [Minizinc](http://www.minizinc.org/), I found the following solution (slightly massaged with `Microsoft Word`):
[image]

Note that I used node number `0..9` rather than `1..10` to compact the matrix text.
There is a huge number of possible solutions. This is just one of them.

**The [Minizinc](http://www.minizinc.org/) script:**

```
include "globals.mzn"; 

set of int: Transceivers = 1..28;
set of int: Nodes = 1..10;

array[Transceivers] of Nodes: node = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,9,10];
array[Transceivers] of Nodes: seq  = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1];

array[Transceivers] of var Transceivers: aTo;

array[Nodes, Nodes] of var Transceivers: connections;

% Each transceiver can only receive from one source at a time
constraint all_different([aTo[t] | t in Transceivers]);

% transceivers have to connect to other nodes rather than to their own node
constraint 
  forall(t in Transceivers) 
    (node[aTo[t]] != node[t]);

% no more than 1 connection between any pair of nodes
constraint
  forall(i in Nodes, j in Nodes where j > i)
    (sum([bool2int((node[t] == i) /\ (node[aTo[t]] == j)) | t in Transceivers]) < 2);    

solve satisfy;

output ["     "] ++ [ show(node[i]-1) ++ "." ++ show(seq[i]) ++ " | " | i in Transceivers] ++
       [ if j == 1 then ("\n" ++ show(node[i]-1) ++ "." ++ show(seq[i]) ++ ": ") else "" endif ++ 
         if fix(aTo[i]) == j then " x  | " else "    | " endif 
        | i in Transceivers, j in Transceivers ];
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I installed  Minizinc and run the program, but I don't understand anything from the output !! Can you explain the output for me, please ?

Comment: What does 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 1.1 | 1.2 | 1.3 | 2.1 | 2.2 | 2.3 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 | 4.1 | 4.2 | 4.3 | 5.1 | 5.2 | 5.3 | 6.1 | 6.2 | 7.1 | 8.1 | 9.1 | means ?

Comment: 0.1 is the first transceiver on node 0. 4.2 is the 2nd transceiver on node 4. The table shows which transceiver is sending to which. So, it is an adjacency matrix.

Comment: If I want to obtain all possible connection matrices .. What change will be in the code?

Comment: If it's not possible to generate all possible connection matrices, How can I generate random connection matrices that match with the above constraints ?

Comment: In the `Minizinc IDE` configuration you can select to generate all solutions. However, this will create many solutions. You can enter a `random seed` in the configuration which might lead to different solutions.

Comment: Where can I enter "random seed" in this code to lead to different solution ? .. Sorry ,I don't have any experience in using Minizinc IDE

Comment: The `MiniZinc Integrated Development Environment (IDE)` has one register tab to edit your script code. The first register tab from the left is "configuration". There your can set parameters for the `MiniZinc` solver. "Random seed" is the fourth parameter counted from the bottom.